# 3D Vector (X, Y, Z) look at Vector

Tags: c++, vector, entity, rotation, angle

Im working with the source sdk (Which uses c++) and I want to rotate a entity's angle so it looks at another entity.

A entity can be looked at as a gameobject or similar and has a position (Vector) in the world as well as a angle (Vector).

I can rotate the entity by using SetAbsAngles which takes a QAngle (Basically a Vector) as parameter.

[image: Explanation of what I want and have]

Comment: If you want answers from people who don't know the source SDK you might want to explain what SetAbsAngles is actually doing and what other means the SDK offers to change an entity's orientation in terms of functions and parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some pseudo-code:

```
vec3 p = entity2->getPosition();
vec3 r = entity1->getPosition();
float xdistance = p[0] - r[0];
float ydistance = p[1] - r[1];
float zdistance = p[2] - r[2];
float xzdistance = sqrt(xdistance * xdistance + zdistance * zdistance);
entitity1->setHeading(atan2(xdistance, zdistance)); // rotation around y
entitity1->setPitch(-atan2(ydistance, xzdistance)); // rotation around x
entitity1->setBank(0); // rotation around z
```

The z-rotation is set to 0 because it cannot be determined. You can set it freely if you like.

This works in a coordinate system with z facing forward, y up and x to the right. If you are using a different system you may have to adjust some signs.

Comment: What is the setHeading, setPitch and setBank?

I don't seem to have these methods in my entity's.

Comment: Heading/Pitch/Bank are terms that describe the y/x/z rotation (in that order). If I understand the source sdk documentation correctly Heading corresponds to -Yaw, Pitch to Pitch, and Bank to Roll. So you would have to use something like SetAbsAngles(QAngle(pitch, -heading, bank));