# Angle y & z from vector3

Tags: rotation, three.js

How to get a rotation.y & rotation.z only (rotation.x = 0) to make a objet lookAt to vector3?

Comment: You want to call object.lookAt( vector ), but you want to constrain the resulting rotation vector to have it's x-component zero? May I ask what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I think that i need convert vector3 to sphere polar coordinates. (not sure)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to constrain `rotation.x` to zero?

Comment: because i have other functions working ok that only works on 2 axis.

Comment: I think you are confused about what the rotation vector represents.

Answer (score 0):

Object3D (on which Mesh) extends has a `lookAt()` function, so does Matrix4.

Have a peek at the [look at sample](http://threejs.org/examples/misc_lookat.html)

[image: look at sample]

Comment: Tnx, but i only need rotation.y & rotation.z / lookAt() calculates x, y and z.

Comment: I imagine you can ignore the x rotation, depending on what planes you use, right ? Also, you still mean looking at in 3D, not 2D, correct ?

Comment: I can't simply ignore x rotation, need to compensate x rotation with y & z.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this way:
(based on this post: [3D Vector (X, Y, Z) look at Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208789/3d-vector-x-y-z-look-at-vector/8208951#8208951))

```
var  vec3 =  new THREE.Vector3(100, 0, 50);

var  xzdistance = Math.sqrt(vec3.x * vec3.x + vec3.z * vec3.z);

var  rotationY =  Math.atan2(vec3.x, vec3.z)  + Math.PI /2;
var  rotationZ = -Math.atan2(vec3.y, xzdistance);
```